# optaplanner solving of one dataset with multiple nodes

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, optaplanner

I'm interested in deploying an optaplanner solution on a Kubernetes cluster. The main interest would be to scale horizontaly the solving of a specific dataset.

I have seen an example of optaplanner with a cluster (implemented thanks to an Optaplanner operator) but in my understanding it scales when multiple problems are submitted (one pod per problem)

So this is not what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a way to "multithread" the computation of the problem (like with the move-thread-count) but accross multiple pods.

Do you know or have heard of any way to do it? I'm not even sure that Optaplanner supports it...

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130151/how-can-i-use-multiple-dynos-for-an-optaplanner-process-on-heroku) says it's not yet supported natively but speak about doing it manually.

Do you have any tips to give for a start?
I would rather find a way to not do partitionned solving since it can miss the optimal solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends.

Are we talking about multi-bet solving? Essentially running the solver in N  clones simultaneously, and picking the best single result out of them? If so, that's where the Operator can help as well.

If we're talking about solving the same problem in a distributed manner, with different machines executing different moves and then incorporating them into one single solution, then no, there is no out-of-the-box solution for that, and I haven't seen any custom implementations of that either.

Honestly, I don't see the benefits of that - the async overhead (and network latency!) will kill performance. The multi-threaded solver already suffers from that, and that's running on a single machine.

My opinion: Having 1 pod run N threads makes just so much more sense to me than having N pods run 1 thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very clear answer, I had a feeling that the network latency could kill the idea but needed confirmation :)  

let's go for a big expensive multicore pod running for a few hours then instead of a few low-cost pods (and that will be easier)

just a last related question @Lukáš Petrovický : about timefold, i read there will be no limitations on the community edition, and also that the multithread is only on enterprise edition.... so, does the community edition has lost multithreading for good? it sadly seems so from my tests... thanks

Comment: Correct, there is no multi-threaded solver in the community edition. (You can still run multiple solvers on multiple threads, just note one solver in multiple threads.) For more, see https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/.